# Cannot navigate from one graph to another one

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

The problem is that I'm in `graph_a` and I need to navigate to `graph_b` withing a deeplink. What is happening is that I also need to navigate from `graph_b` to `graph_a` so I have included in graph_a the `graph_b` so I can navigate with a deeplink to any destination inside `graph_b` from `graph_a`

This is working fine, but the problem is that from `graph_b` if I include graph_a I get a ciclic inclusion in both graphs which causes my app to freeze on startup and not load anything, if I try to navigate without including `graph_a` into my `graph_b` I get this error

> Navigation destination that matches request Nav DeepLink Request {uri
> = test://home } cannot be found in the navigation graph NavGraph (graph_b)

What can I do ?

Comment: How do `graph_a` and `graph_b` relate to your entire app's navigation graph? If they are siblings, then neither should directly include the other.

Comment: they are two different graphs that need to communicate each one to the other one @ianhanniballake graph_a is the main one, and graph_b is another graph that needs to know graph_a deeplink uris to navigate to each destination

Comment: Your error message when you don't include `graph_a` into `graph_b` indicates that you've called `setGraph(graph_b)` and you are not using `graph_b` as part of `graph_a`. Which is it?